# Jquery validation equalTo function doesn't work when input value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with captcha. Validations are working fine when the page load. But users can reload captcha with a different value. In that time jquery validation is not working. `equalTo` function check the first value of that input field, not the last value after reload. Please help me to fix it.

HTML

```
<div class="refreshcaptcha dispinitial"><input type="text"></div>
```

JQuery validation

```
$("#hireform").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore"
    , errorElement: "label"
    , errorClass: "has-error"
    , submitHandler: function (e) {  
        e.submit()
    }
    , highlight: function (e) {
        $(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("success").addClass("has-error")
    }
    , rules: {
        name: {
            required: !0
            , maxlength: 45
        }
        , email: {
            required: !0
            , maxlength: 100
        }
        , message: {
            required: !0
            , minlength: 6
            , maxlength: 1500
        }
        , captcha: {
            equalTo: $('#hireform').find('.refreshcaptcha>input')
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution.

1. Can use `equalTo` function inside the input field. Or
2. Create a `equalTo: "#cap_val_reload"` in the jquery

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="captcha" equalTo="#cap_val_reload" class="form-control captchauser" minlength="5" required maxlength="5" value="" placeholder="Please enter above value">
```

JQuery

```
$("#hireform").validate({
  ignore: ".ignore"
  , errorElement: "label"
  , errorClass: "has-error"
  , submitHandler: function (e) {  
      e.submit()
  }
  , highlight: function (e) {
      $(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("success").addClass("has-error")
  }
  , rules: {
      name: {
          required: !0
          , maxlength: 45
      }
      , email: {
          required: !0
          , maxlength: 100
      }
      , message: {
          required: !0
          , minlength: 6
          , maxlength: 1500
      }
      , captcha: {
          required: !0
          equalTo: "#cap_val_reload"
      }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Store captcha value as a constant, when refreshed change this constant. and in validation check if catcha equal to constant.
Cant help much without seeing more code.

Comment: There is a button for users to change the value in `.refreshcaptcha>input`. Just image when they click that button this value will keep changing again and again. So I want to equal to those value. When I use `equalTo ` function it checks the first value. not the last value which user changed. Hope u get it.

Comment: I assume its not google captcha.. When user presses refreshes button, replace the new value to the constant. and in validation check if captcha equals constant.. Hope you get it

Comment: It's not google captcha. I use some default function in CodeIgniter framework. I use ajax to reload the captcha and change the value. I tried constant value but didn't workout.

Comment: When page loads assign javascript constant captcha value,
in the success of ajax call change this constant to new value,
Then 
captcha: {
            equalTo: constantName
        }

Answer (score 0):

maybe use .change()

```js
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
  alert("work")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

[Click for Explain](https://api.jquery.com/change/)